# one model with complete animation becomes 100+ animation clips after export from blender

Tags: export

I downloaded a model from sketchfab with fbx format and import into blender 2.8 or 2.79,in blender everything is right,animation works without doubt,but when I chose to export again to fbx or glb,after export,I open the model,I got 100+ animation clips as shown below:[image]

here is the original sketchfab link:
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/log-cutter-splitter-e2285f2f17fc4cc9a8fc2010ad85e794
Can any one help me with this strange issue?thanks!

Comment: Because in Blender every object has its own action. To prevent the multiple animation action export disable the "NLA Strips" and "All actions" in the fbx exporter's animation tab.

Comment: Hi @freakyuito, the title of the question could be clearer, hopefully attracting the right people to answer.  I hope this advice is helpful.